# How to append elements to char *var[] in C?

Tags: c

I have this variable:

```
char *var[] = {get_answer(answers, 0), get_answer(answers, 1)};
```

I want to add `get_answer(answers, 2)` as the third element of the `var[]` and this is what I have tried:

```
var[2] = get_answers(answers, 2);
```

It didn't seem to do anything.
How should I go about appending elements to the said variable?

Comment: 1. You are initializing an aray with the result of function calls. Initializers are compile time, so this can't work (what did your compiler warnings tell your?) 2. Even so, the var only has two elements, so you can't "append" an element. You could declare the var to be 3 elements.

Comment: You should consider using other data structures (i.e. linked list, ...) that can dynamically add an element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The size of the array `var` is automatically determined based on the number of elements you provide during initialization. It doesn't change as you assign more elements to it. So, you can't assign at `var[2]`.

You can either dynamically allocate the array of pointers using `malloc()`. Or provide more elements during initialization, such as NULL pointers. Or explicitly provide the size of the array.

```
char *var[] = {get_answer(answers, 0), get_answer(answers, 1), NULL, NULL, NULL}; // 5 elements
```

or

```
char *var[10] = {get_answer(answers, 0), get_answer(answers, 1), NULL, NULL, NULL}; // 10 elements
```

Answer (score 0):

The array defined as:

```
char *var[] = {get_answer(answers, 0), get_answer(answers, 1)};
```

has "fixed" size of two elements. It is the same as you would write:

```
char *var[2] = {get_answer(answers, 0), get_answer(answers, 1)};
```

Hence, there is no room for third element.

There are two basic choices:

1) Declare `var` with room for additional entry (or entries):

```
char *var[3] = {get_answer(answers, 0), get_answer(answers, 1)};
// ...
var[2] = get_answers(answers, 2);
```

2) Initilize with third element in place:

```
char *var[] = {get_answer(answers, 0), get_answer(answers, 1), get_answers(answers, 2)};
```